# Wildcard certificate usage search with Powershell or Command prompt

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a bash command

`curl -v --silent https://abc.xyz/ 2>&1 | grep "CN=\*.xyz.com" -c`

this works fine from a Ubuntu machine but I want to convert or use a similar command in Powershell or in CMD. I tried a bunch of variations like:

`curl https://abc.xyz/ 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern "CN=\*.xyz.com"`

`curl -E -Uri https://abc.xyz/ 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern "CN=\*.xyz.com"`

`Invoke-WebRequest https://abc.xyz/ 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern "CN=\*.xyz.com"`

What I noticed in PS commands is, it's not outputting the common name to check the pattern with.
My actual need is to check if the wildcard cert used in `https://abc.xyz/` or not.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My actual need is to check if the wildcard cert used in https://abc.xyz/ or not.

In this example, we'll check if a wildcard cert is used on **msn.com**:

```
$url = 'https://www.msn.com'
$req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)
$req.GetResponse() | Out-Null
$cerName = $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetName()
$cerName -match 'CN=\*\.msn\.com'
```

Output:

```
True
```